# ResponseEntity objects not released after response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

ResponseEntity objects are not released after response.
They still remain in heap space with their body (data) even if i execute full gc.
So my question is

- Is it normal?
- If it's not whats potential cuases?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you got any updates on this? I'm facing the same issue here.

Comment: @bielelele 
I reported it on spring github, and they said it is a bug.
I didn't check it but they may fixed it in recent version of spring web

Comment: Thanks for replying! Would you mind sharing the issue link?

Comment: @bielelele https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28232